# Android Service Multiple Threads and startForeground()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I have a `Service` that facilitates the downloading of files from a server. Everytime an `Intent` is received in `onStartCommand`, I start a new `Thread`, put the `Thread` into a map with the url being downloaded as the key, and create a notification to show the progress of the download. If there are no `Thread`s in the map, a flag is set in the `Thread` that signifies that it should use `startForeground` when the `Notification`is being created or updated. Subsequent `Thread`s/`Notification`s are show using `NotificationManager.notify` with the `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL` off and the `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` on. Each `Thread` has its own unique id that is sent to `startForeground` or `notify`. When the file is finished downloading, or the user cancels the download (by pressing a button in the `Notification`'s `RemoteView`, if it is the "foreground thread/notification," `stopForeground(true)` is called, the `Notification` is populated with a new `RemoteView` that shows whether the download completed or not, and the next running `Thread` has its "foreground" flag set to `true`.

The problem is, if I have, let's say, two files downloading, there will be one `Notification`/`Thread` that is connected to `startForeground` and one that is not. If I cancel the "foreground" one, everything is fine. However, if I press the cancel button on the non-foreground one, the foreground one is dismissed (and pressing the cancel button again will then dismiss the proper one). If I don't cancel any, and I start a 3rd download that completes before the others, the completed `Notification` shows, but the other two that are still going start to blink and rapidly move up and down in the status bar.

How do I make sure that the `Service` will always be in the foreground as long as there are downloads going on, without the notifications jumping around in the situation noted above, and with the cancelling working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was making a variable in the `Service` called `isInForeground` that is global to all of the `Thread`s. It signifies whether `startForeground` has been called, without a subsequent call to `stopForeground`.

In my `updateNotification` method, I check `isInForeground`. If it is `false` I set it to `true`, set the `Thread`'s `isForegroundNotification` flag to `true`, and call `startForeground` with that `Thread`'s `Notification`. In my `stopNotification` method, if the `Thread`'s `isForegroundNotification` is `true`, I set it and `isInForeground` to `false` and call `stopForeground(true)`.